# What impact do higher refresh-rate screens have on the laptop itself?

Tags: laptop, display, refresh-rate, 120hz

I understand that through a higher refresh rate, you can 'feel' the higher FPS and mouse movement in games and interactive applications. However, aside from human detection, **what impact do higher refresh-rate screens have on the overal computer itself?**

For example, if I have a laptop with a `60hz` screen and another laptop with the exact same specifications except its screen having a refresh rate of `120hz`, what effect would this have on the laptop itself? Does it consume more power? Are any hardware components besides the screen effected by this? Are there any other notable things to be aware of with an increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *theoretically* it consumes more power but not proportionally, i.e., it won't consume the double just because it has double the refresh rate. That said, the aforementioned consideration is only valid (and only makes sense) if the panels, other than the refresh rate, are really identical. Otherwise you'd be "comparing apples with oranges".

No other components are effected nor there's something "notable" about this.

Comment: Is there any reason not to get a higher refresh rate screen (besides being more expensive)?

Comment: I can't think of one, honestly :)